# tor failed to establish a network connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, network-configuration, connection, browsers

IDK whats the problem, it worked till now.

> Blockquote 7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:02 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:02 PM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:08 PM.700 [WARN] Received a bad CERTS cell: At least one certificate expired. 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:09 PM.700 [WARN] Received a bad CERTS cell: At least one certificate expired. 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:09 PM.700 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 24E2F1239121D4394C54B5BCC368B3B411857C413 at XXX) 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:09 PM.700 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:09 PM.700 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:10 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:10 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:10 PM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
>   7/10/2018 13:08:10 PM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:52 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:52 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:52 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:52 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN] Received a bad CERTS cell: At least one certificate expired. 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host BD6A8292545CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at XXX) 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 40E7D6CE5085E4CDDDA31D51A29D1457EB53F12AD at XXX) 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.200 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
>   7/10/2018 13:09:53 PM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
>   Blockquote

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Given the errors you are suddenly receiving, there are some questions I am going to ask.

Let's take a look at one of them.
Blockquote 7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 7/10/2018 13:08:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges")

Are you trying to access tor from an area where the tor network is blocked (given that it says "was using bridges")? If you were having to use bridges to connect, your ISP might have discovered that the ip addresses that you were connecting to were bridges and blocked them. You can get more bridges by sending an email with the subject line "Get Bridges" to bridges@torproject.org from an either gmail.com or yahoo.com email address or going to https://bridges.torproject.org/

If this is not the case and you were not having to use bridges to connect to the tor network (if the tor network is not blocked by your ISP), the next thing I would ask is this; have you changed anything on your network (firewall settings, added a proxy server, etc)? If this is the case, well then you'll need to click the "configure" button on the tor software and enter the proxy settings of your local proxy server if you have one, or configure tor browser to connect only through ports that are not blocked through your router or firewall (assuming you cannot possibly change this, which can be done by logging into your router and configuring your router to allow the necessary traffic).

Let me know what you think.